# Binary Operations $x,y \in S$

Tags: binary-operations

Trying to understand binary operations, but seriously confused. I was looking at all the videos on youtube, forums, but I think I must be missing something.

I have a set $$S = \{a, b, c, d, e \}$$ and for $x,y  \in S$ define the binary operation $*$ on $S$ by  $x*y=y$. **It is this form, so please stop changing it!**

I'm trying to build a table to represent it, to show $*$ on $S$.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You mean $S = \{a,b,c,d,e\}$ right ?

Comment: Sorry yes. Whoops

Comment: What is it you don't understand?

Comment: Really any of it at all. I have no idea where to start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A binary operation $*$ on a set $S$ is nothing more than a bunch of assignments. Here, we assign to each pair of elements of $S$ another element of $S$. So, either $*$ is defined for you already, or you define $*$ so that

$a*a = $ something in $S$

$a*b = $ something in $S$ (could be the same something as above, or it could be different)

$a*c = $ something in $S$ (ditto)

and so on for every pair of elements.

You mentioned an operation table, which is a fine way to represent an operation on a set of this size. Draw a $6 \times 6$ grid similar to the one in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280272/group-of-order-5/1280313#1280313), only instead of using the symbols in that grid, use the symbols $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, and $e$. The row in yellow is usually called the master row, and you should have each element of $S$ in it. Similarly for the master column. Now, for the "lower-right" $25$ elements, fill in each box with one of the elements of $S$.

Now, to find, say, $b*d$, start with the row where the leftmost (yellow) entry is $b$. Search along that row until you find the column where the topmost (yellow) entry is $d$. The value in that box is what you have assigned to $b*d$.

Edit: Now that I see that for each $x,y \in S$, $x*y=y$, this task becomes clearer. Simply assign $a*a = a$, $a*b = b$, and so forth.

Comment: ok, so no matter what the y value is in x*y=y, that is what we put in the box?

Comment: Yes. $a*c = c$, $a*d = d$, $a*e=e$, $b*a = a$, and so forth. You will see a pattern when you are done filling in the grid.

Comment: What I end up with, is a column of a the b then c and so on. Like the columns are all the same as the topmost entry. Is the correct?

Comment: Yes indeed, you got it. :)

Comment: Awesome thank you, then this we would describe as * being a binary operation on S. Then I would say it it is associative as it uniquely pairs each element to an element in S correct?

Comment: Well, to show it's associative, you must show that for all $x,y,z \in S$ that $x*(y*z) = (x*y)*z$. Luckily this isn't too bad, since you know what the result of any $*$ operation is.

Comment: Hmm, ok. So do I just go through a number of examples to prove that.

Comment: That's one approach, but not the most effective since you have a formula. Here's how you'd start: Let $x,y,z \in S$. Then $x*(y*z) = x* z = \dots$. Also, $(x*y)*z = \dots$. (You'll eventually obtain that these two expressions are equal.)

Comment: x*(y*z) = x*z=....that is confusing me.

Comment: No matter what elements $y$ and $z$ are, you have that $y*z = z$, right?

Comment: Ohh, then the other side would also equal that.

Answer (score 2):

Well stating that $x*y = y$ pretty well defines it in my opinion...if you mean list the full function (i.e. each of $25$ permutations of $x, y$), then you just list it.

As a table:

\begin{array}{c | c  c c c c}
* & \textbf{a} & \textbf{b} & \textbf{c} & \textbf{d} & \textbf{e} \\ \hline 
\textbf{a} & a & b & c & d & e \\ 
\textbf{b} & a & b & c & d & e \\ 
\textbf{c} & a & b & c & d & e \\ 
\textbf{d} & a & b & c & d & e \\ 
\textbf{e} & a & b & c & d & e \\ 
\end{array}

Each row is identical because any value $*a$ gives $a$, and any value $*b$  gives $b$, etc.

Comment: Why is your table so different to the one below?

Comment: It is different because the guy below assumes  the latin square property while this fellow doesn't. as I said, you can have ANY rule you so choose. It can be a random clusterfuck if you so want and it'd be fine.

Comment: ok, ok @ZelosMalum is right, my table satisfies more property (Group), but it is still a binary operation (Useful one), but this table is also possible

Comment: Well I was actually trying to answer the question which is was to define the binary operation $*$ such that $x*y = y$.  The fact that this function does not appear to have the latin square property proves that this operation does _not_ form a group (I think)...which this binary operation certainly does not allow for an identity (since $x*e = e \neq x$) and this operation isn't commutative (and even if it were, an inverse cannot exist if an identity doesn't).

Answer (score 1):

A binary operation is a function $f(x,y)$ that produces a third element that may or maynot be distinct from the previous two elements, it is however more commonly written with some figure like $x\cdot y$, $x\circ y$, $x\diamond y$ etc.

In many instances when we have that $\forall x,y\in S$ and $x\circ y\in S$ we say it is a closed operation because it produces nothing outside of the given set, in many instances we also have what is called the neutral/identity element where $x\circ e=x$ for all $x\in S$.

For representing it with a small finite set, like your $S$ you can do it with a table like on [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Latin_Square) where the top row represent either the left or right element while the first column represent the other element and then you see what they produce.

Comment: That is exactly what I have been reading, and that is what I don't understand. I don't get how x*y=y comes into play, which is the x row in the table, and which is the y? How do I determine the values in the table. That just looked like another definition.

Comment: If you define the function yourself, your choice really! You can define the binary operation anyway you so want, you can even decied that there is no identity element.

Comment: I'm confused...so I can put in any values I want with that information I provided?

Comment: A binary operation is just a general idea, if YOU DEFINE a binary operation it is YOUR CHOICE how it works, you can choose ANYTHING you want. That is the thing, it is not specific, it has no definite rules HOW it must be constructed, the only criteria is that ALL elements of S must be used to produce SOME element but not necciserly ALL elements, you can have

$x\circ y = a$ for any $x,y\in S$ if you want and it goes.

Comment: so what is the $x*y=y$ for?

Comment: That merely states one of two cases, either the binary operation is independed of $x$ and $y$ determines everything, OR it indicates that our $x$ is the identity element.

Comment: yea, I can't say any of these explanations really made any sense at all. Im still stuck at stage one, where I would just put 'a' in every spot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24245/discussion-between-zelos-malum-and-thecrownedpixel).

Answer (score 1):

A binary operation is an operation that takes two elements (pair) of some set and then map them uniquely to an element in the same set.

Formally, a binary operation on a non empty set $S$ is a  map  $$f:S \times S \to S$$ that have the following properties

(1) $f$ is defined for every pair of elements in $S$

(2) $f$ uniquely associates each pair of elements in $S$ to some element of $S$

You can have a lot of binary operations on the set $S$ that you provided but for instance if your binary operation $*$ has map $a*b = c$ then it can't be true that $a*d = c$ as well, it fails the second property of the binary operation. This is how you can build your table, assume $a*b=c$ then $a*c \neq c$ but maybe $=d,e,f$ and if you chose that $a*c =d$ then $a*d \neq c,d$ but it can be equal to $e,f$ and so on, you see where is that going !

Below is a possible table for the binary operation $*$ on $S$

> $$
> \begin{array}{c|lcr}
>  *& e & a & b & c & d \\
> \hline
> e & e & a & b & c & d \\
> a & a & b & c & d & e \\
> b & b & c & d & e & a \\
> c & c & d & e & a & b \\
> d & d & e & a & b & c
> \end{array}$$

is an example of a table for a binary operation that satisfies the two properties, as a matter of fact, this is a table of a group with operation $*$ as well as the identity is the element $e$, This table is actually very easy to build, do you see the shifting in each row  and also this table is symmetric meaning that row 1= col1, row 2= col2 and so on, It's also commutative table, $a*b = b*a = e$ and so on.

Keep in mind, that this is not the only table that you can build, actually a table that has distinct elements row wise  and column wise is also valid, for example a row which has $$a \space a \space  b \space  c \space d$$ is not allowed but a row which has $$c \space d \space  e \space b \space a$$ is allowed , same for columns, there are many tables that can be generated, can you count how many tables are possible ??

Comment: That doesn't really get me anywhere though, as it is a definition. I'm not understanding the definition. How do I take the elements I have and turn them into a table.

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: It doesn't have to be associative, associativity is a nice property but not neccisery.

Comment: Ok, so from that information I can build the table. Can I put any values in the table? Could you explain the property's a little more for me.

Comment: I made a table !!

Comment: You can put any values you have in $S$ really if you want it to be closed, otherwise anything goes really. Keep in mind though that it doesn't HAVE TO be associative

Comment: @ZelosMalum ok. It seems like a strange question to ask a student who I learning this for the first time. There was no explanation that the rules of the table could be anything.

Comment: Technically the fact that the definitions contains no restrictions means it can be anything. That which is left unspecified are you free to change and do anything you so want with.

Comment: @TheCrownedPixel , the table must satisfy the two properties of the binary operation

Comment: meaning that $a*b=e$ and $a*b =d$ is not allowed for instance

Comment: How does the answer that Jared left help? Is that correct? That seems like it answers my question kinda.

Comment: An easy way to build the table is to make sure that each row has distinct value for example a row can't have two a's or two b's, same for columns

Comment: Acctually you can have $a\ast b = \{e,d\}$ if you want, it's just not terribly useful by most accounts then.

Comment: Re Read the answer after my edit @TheCrownedPixel

Comment: It's still technically not correct, you ARE allowed to have any element, it is as I said though, in most places not terribly useful if it is. You are assuming the latin square property here which isn't neccisery always

Comment: @TheCrownedPixel check this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k9CPlb9kpeA