# How to determine if certain operation is associative based on Cayley table

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have the following table and I don't know how to determine if an operation is associative based on the table. Is there an easy way to do it? Or it's just brute force

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
*& a & b & c &d &e \\ \hline
 a& a&b &c&b&d\\ \hline
 b&  b&c &a&e&c\\ \hline
 c& c &a &b&b&a\\ \hline
 d&b&e&b&e&d\\ \hline
 e&d&b&a&d&c\\ \hline
\end{array}

We can see that it's not commutative because $b*e \neq e*b$, but how do we check if it's associative?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/168663/11206

Answer (score 3):

In general, it is not possible to check for associativity simply by glancing at the Cayley table. This is, in part, because associativity is determined from a three termed equation $a(bc) = (ab)c$ whilst the Cayley table shows two-term products only.

However, you don't quite need brute force. You can use [Light's associativity test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light%27s_associativity_test).

Answer (score 2):

*Light's associativity test* is based on the following Lemma.
Let  $*$ be a binary operation on the set $S$ (called product).

**Definition:**
A subset $G$ of $S$ generates $S$ if every element of $S$ can be generated as product of elements of $G$.

**Lemma:** If G generates S then * is associative on S if and only if
   $$\forall (x \in S) \forall (g \in G) \forall (z \in S): x*(g*z)=(x*g)*z$$

---

In your example $\{e\}$ generates $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$, because

$$e=e$$
$$c=e^2$$
$$a=e*c=e*(e^2)$$
$$d=a*e=(e*(e^2))*e$$
$$b=a*d=(e*(e^2))*((e*(e^2))*e)$$

so you have to check

$$\forall (x \in S) \forall (z \in S): x*(e*z)=(x*e)*z$$

But we have 
$$c*(e*e)=c*c=b$$
$$(c*e)*e=a*e=a$$
and so
 $$c*(e*e) \ne (c*e)*e$$
So $*$ is not associative.

Answer (score 0):

Do two "outer products" using the multiplication table (but the dimensions in different orders). Then you compare the resulting outer products element-wise.