# How can one construct a strict quasigroup with neither a left nor a right identity on $n$ elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, quasigroups

When I say $Q$ is a strict quasigroup, I only mean that $Q$ is a quasigroup that is neither a loop nor is it associative.

In general, I can find a quasigroup on $n$ elements with neither a left nor a right identity. If I need an example of one of these I generally just look at the Cayley table for the cyclic group of order $n$:

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
 & 1 & 2 & \cdots & n\\ \hline
      1 & 1 & 2 & \cdots & n\\
      2 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & 1\\
      \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
      n & n & 1 & \cdots & n-1\\
\end{array}
$$
Swap the first $2$ rows:
$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
 & 1 & 2 & \cdots & n\\ \hline
      1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & 1\\
      2 & 1 & 2 & \cdots & n\\
      \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
      n & n & 1 & \cdots & n-1\\
\end{array}
$$
Then swap the first $2$ columns:
     $$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
& 1 & 2 & \cdots & n\\ \hline
  1 & 3 & 2 & \cdots & 1\\
  2 & 2 & 1 & \cdots & n\\
  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
  n & 1 & n & \cdots & n-1\\
\end{array}
$$ 
And the result is a quasigroup with neither a left nor a right identity. The problem is that the quasigroup that results from this process is in general associative, and [there is no way to tell if an operation is not associative simply by looking at a Cayley table](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168663/is-there-an-easy-way-to-see-associativity-or-non-associativity-from-an-operation). So I am wondering, if I want to construct a strict quasigroup on $n$ elements which has neither a left nor a right identity, how would I go about doing that?

It feels like this would be something simple to do, but so far I haven't been able to!

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of swapping the first two columns, swap the first and third column.  Then there will still be no identity on either side since $2\cdot 2=2$ so $2$ is the only possible identity but $2\cdot 1=3$ and $1\cdot 2=3$.  Moreover, the quasigroup is not associative because (for instance) $$(1\cdot 2)\cdot 2=3\cdot 2=4$$ (or $1$ if $n=3$) and $$1\cdot (2\cdot 2)=1\cdot 2=3.$$

Note that this works only if $n\geq 3$.  If $n\leq 1$ then obviously it is impossible and for $n=2$ it is easy to see that any quasigroup must have an identity element.

Answer (score 0):

Another example of the same kind is from the Cayley table of the subtraction $\mod n$, for $n\ge3$, a quasigroup operation where $0$ is a right identity and there is no left identity element. For example, for $n=4$ we have:
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
-_{4} & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
\hline
0 & \color{red}{0} & 3 & 2 & 1\\
1 & \color{red}{1} & 0 & 3 & 2\\
2 & \color{red}{2} & 1 & 0 & 3\\
3 & \color{red}{3} & 2 & 1 & 0\\
\end{array}
$$
The right identity is highlighted in red. Now swapping, for example, the $(n-1)$-th line and the $n$-th (here the third and the fourth) we get:
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\bullet & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 3 & 2 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 2\\
3 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0\\
2 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 3\\
\end{array}
$$