# Show that $(S,*)$ is a group,where $S=\left\{a,b,c,e\right\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, binary-operations

Given a set $S=\left\{a,b,c,e\right\}$ equipped with a binary operation $*:S \times S \to S$,such that
$$a^2=b^2=c^2=abc=e.$$

Show that based on the table

$$
\begin{array}{r|rr}
*&e&a&b&c&\\\hline e&e&a&b&c\\
a&\;a&e&c&b\\
b&\;b&c&e&a\\
c&\;c&b&a&e
\end{array}
$$

$(S,*)$ is an Abelian group.

---

$S$ is closed under $*$ since the elements on each raw are members contained in $S$, every element is it's own inverse and the identity element is $e$, moreover, $*$ is commutative since the table is symmetric along the main diagonal.

I have two questions:

- How to show that $*$ is associative, I checked and there are $\binom{4}{1} \binom{3}{1} \binom{2}{1} =24$ cases to be checked and this is frustrating, so does there exist a better way?
- If I have  only the presentation $a^2=b^2=c^2=abc=e$, then how should I draw the Cayley table? I only could form the following table:

$$
\begin{array}{r|rr}
*&e&a&b&c&\\\hline e\\
a&\;&e&c&b\\
b&\;&c&e&a\\
c&\;&b&a&e
\end{array}
$$

How to fill the others with the given presentation?

Comment: For a group, all elements of the same row/column of the Cayley table must be distinct because of the cancellation rule.

Comment: $e$ is supposed to be the neutral element. So you should be able to fill in your Cayley table.

Answer (score 2):

You can construct a bijection:
$$
\varphi:S\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2
$$
defined by
\begin{align}
\varphi(e)&:=(0,0),\\
\varphi(a)&:=(1,0),\\
\varphi(b)&:=(0,1),\\
\varphi(c)&:=(1,1).
\end{align}
Now use the Cayley table of $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ to write the Cayley table of $S$.

These tables are the "same", in the sense that if an element $x\in S$ appears in the entry $(i,j)$ of the Cayley table of $S$, then $\varphi(x)\in\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ is in the entry $(i,j)$ of the Cayley table of $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$. This shows that $S$ is a group.

$S$ is abelian because $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ is such.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have
\begin{array}{r|rr}
&e&a&b&c&\\\hline e\\
a&\;&e&c&b\\
b&\;&c&e&a\\
c&\;&b&a&e
\end{array}
you can complete it uniquely, because in the Cayley table for a group no element can appear twice in a row or in a column.

You can get this table from the data $a^2=b^2=c^2=abc=e$, because *if* you want to get a group, from $c^2=e$ and $abc=e$ you must get $ab=c$; similarly, from $a^2=abc=e$ you get $bc=a$ (division in groups is unique).

Now you want a group, so it must have a neutral element and only $e$ can be. so you can fill in the table
\begin{array}{r|rr}
&e&a&b&c&\\\hline
e &e&a&b&c\\
a&a&e&c&b\\
b&b&c&e&a\\
c&c&b&a&e
\end{array}
But is this a group? If it is, then the table has been realized uniquely. How to check associativity? You don't need to. Consider the map
$$
f\colon\{a,b,c,e\}\to S_4
$$
defined by $f(a)=(12)(34)$, $f(b)=(13)(24)$, $f(c)=(14)(23)$, $f(e)$ being the identity. This map respects the operations on the two sets by direct checking and the image is a subgroup of $S_4$.

Answer (score 0):

We can check associativity of the Cayley table more easily as follows, see

[Is there an easy way to see associativity or non-associativity from an operation's table?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168663/is-there-an-easy-way-to-see-associativity-or-non-associativity-from-an-operation)

"Direct verification of the associativity of a binary operation specified by a Cayley table is cumbersome and tedious. Light's associativity test greatly simplifies the task."